# Installing Wine 4.20 but winegcc: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc failed

Tags: mac, terminal, 64-bit, wine, gcc

I'm trying to install Wine 4.20 for the first time on a new MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) running MacOS Monterey (v12.1). I downloaded from winehq, entered `./configure --enable-win64`, and then typed `make`. After compiling for a while, it aborted unexpectedly with the following error message:

```
../../tools/winegcc/winegcc -o d2d1.dll --wine-objdir ../.. -b x86_64-w64-mingw32 --lib-suffix=.cross.a \
  -Wl,--wine-builtin -shared d2d1.spec -mno-cygwin bitmap.cross.o bitmap_render_target.cross.o \
  brush.cross.o dc_render_target.cross.o device.cross.o effect.cross.o factory.cross.o \
  geometry.cross.o hwnd_render_target.cross.o layer.cross.o mesh.cross.o state_block.cross.o \
  stroke.cross.o wic_render_target.cross.o version.res ../../dlls/dwrite/libdwrite.delay.a \
  ../../dlls/d3d10_1/libd3d10_1.cross.a ../../dlls/dxguid/libdxguid.cross.a \
  ../../dlls/uuid/libuuid.cross.a ../../dlls/gdi32/libgdi32.cross.a \
  ../../dlls/user32/libuser32.cross.a ../../dlls/advapi32/libadvapi32.cross.a 
/usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_4/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: brush.cross.o: in function `d2d_brush_fill_cb':
/Users/spideyjoe47/downloads/wine-4.20/dlls/d2d1/brush.c:1215: undefined reference to `sincosf'
/usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_4/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: factory.cross.o: in function `D2D1MakeRotateMatrix':
/Users/spideyjoe47/downloads/wine-4.20/dlls/d2d1/factory.c:605: undefined reference to `sincosf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
winegcc: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc failed
make[1]: *** [d2d1.dll] Error 2
make: *** [dlls/d2d1] Error 2
```

Comment: “undefined reference to `sincosf'” - This type of error happens when you don’t have all the source files required to build the project